# Button does not cause c# function to run

Tags: c#, html, button

So here is my code

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="jumbotron" >
        <h1>Welcome to BodySpace</h1>
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <!--<form class="form-signin" id="SignInForm" action="Default.aspx/#SignInForm"> -->
           <table><tr><td>&nbsp; <asp:TextBox type="email" runat="server" name="email" id="email" ValidationGroup="LogIn" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
        <td>&nbsp; <asp:TextBox type="password" runat="server" name="pass" id="pass" ValidationGroup="LogIn" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required /></td>
            <td>&nbsp; <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-success" text="Sign-In" ID="SignInButton" ValidationGroup="LogIn" onclick="SignInButton_Click" /></td><td><label runat="server" id="failedLogin">Incorrect email and password combination</label></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td><a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Sign in with Facebook</a></td>
            </tr></table><!--</form>-->
        </div>
      </div>
          <!--<form class="form-group" id="RegisterForm" action="Default.aspx/#RegisterForm"> -->
          <table><tr><td>
    <h3>This website and all of it's
    </h3>
        <h3>contents are and will remain free</h3>
    <table><tr><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" name="fNameReg" id="fNameReg" ValidationGroup="Register" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox type="text" runat="server" name="lNameReg" id="lNameReg" ValidationGroup="Register" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required /></td>
          </tr></table>
           <br /><asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" name="emailReg" id="emailReg" ValidationGroup="Register" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email adress" title="Must be a valid email adress" required pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z]+([0-9a-zA-Z]*[-._+])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-Z]+([-.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*([0-9a-zA-Z]*[.])[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" />
           <br /><asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" name="emailRegCheck" id="emailRegCheck" ValidationGroup="Register" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype your email adress" required />
           <br /><asp:TextBox runat="server" type="password" name="passwordReg" id="passwordReg" ValidationGroup="Register" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" title="Minimum 8 characters, one number, one uppercase and one lowercase letter" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$" />
           <table>
           <tr>
              <h4> Birth day</h4>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dayReg" runat="server" cssClass="form-control" >
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Invalid">Day</asp:ListItem>
                           </asp:DropDownList>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="monthReg" runat="server" cssClass="form-control" onchange="popDayReg()" >
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                           </asp:DropDownList>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="yearReg" runat="server" cssClass="form-control"  onchange="popDayReg()">
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Invalid">Year</asp:ListItem>
                           </asp:DropDownList>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
           <label class="checkbox-inline"><input runat="server" type="radio" name="sexReg" id="maleReg" value="male" checked="true" />Male</label>
           <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" name="sexReg" id="femaleReg" value="female"/>Female</label>
           <br /><asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-success" 
                  text="Register" ID="RegisterButton" ValidationGroup="Register" onclick="RegisterButton_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <div><img alt="Image did not load :(" class="style1" src="../Images/bbingguy.jpg" /></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label runat="server" id="failedRegister">Oh no, something went wrong with your registration. Please try again</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <!--</form>-->
    </form>
</body>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SignInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //runs

    }
    protected void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //does not run
    }
}
```

My question is,
The first submit button (login button) causes it's C# function to run but the 2nd submit button (register button) does not run, anyone has a clue why?

EDIT: both the buttons cause postback but the 2nd button doesn't run it's function, I could clean up the code but I'm worried it would delete the source of the problem since I am a novice with website building and such.

Comment: Can you please provide minimal sample that demonstrates the problem. Also there some random text in post...

Comment: If you have asp button then why you add type="submit" in that button syntax. Try to remove that

Comment: @Piyush it didn't work, button still caused postback but not the function, as to why I had both, because nobody taught us otherwise :S (at school that is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple Form tag inside the form tags. Form tag cant be nested inside the form tags.
You can have multiple HTML form tags in a page, but they cannot be nested within one another.

So remove the nested form tags, and only make page using only one form tag. then it works fine

Remove both Form tags mentioned here

Your final code will be , after remove nested form tag and implement validationgroup

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome to BodySpace</h1>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox type="email" runat="server" name="email" ID="email" class="input-block-level" ValidationGroup="SignIn" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;
                            <input type="password" runat="server" name="pass" id="pass" class="input-block-level" ValidationGroup="SignIn" placeholder="Password" required /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Sign-In" ID="SignInButton" ValidationGroup="SignIn" OnClick="SignInButton_Click" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label runat="server" id="failedLogin">Incorrect email and password combination</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Sign in with Facebook</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>This website and all of it's
                    </h3>
                    <h3>contents are and will remain free</h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input runat="server" type="text" name="fNameReg" id="fNameReg" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" runat="server" name="lNameReg" id="lNameReg" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" name="emailReg" ID="emailReg" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email adress" title="Must be a valid email adress" required pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z]+([0-9a-zA-Z]*[-._+])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-Z]+([-.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*([0-9a-zA-Z]*[.])[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" />
                    <br />
                    <input runat="server" type="text" name="emailRegCheck" id="emailRegCheck" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype your email adress" required />
                    <br />
                    <input runat="server" type="password" name="passwordReg" id="passwordReg" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" title="Minimum 8 characters, one number, one uppercase and one lowercase letter" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$" />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <h4>Birth day</h4>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dayReg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Invalid">Day</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="monthReg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" onchange="popDayReg()">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="yearReg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" onchange="popDayReg()">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Invalid">Year</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input runat="server" type="radio" name="sexReg" id="maleReg" value="male" />Male</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="sexReg" id="femaleReg" value="female" />Female</label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
                        Text="Register" ID="RegisterButton" OnClick="RegisterButton_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <img alt="Image did not load :(" class="style1" src="../Images/bbingguy.jpg" /></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label runat="server" id="failedRegister">Oh no, something went wrong with your registration. Please try again</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok and then how do I make the  first button validate only the email and password fields and the 2nd button validate only the other fields?

Comment: you can use validategroup property to use validate multiple fields on different button on single page

Comment: Do you mean to add a ValidationGroup attribute to all my elements and make 2 groups for example Register & Login?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  For example, if you have two sets here Sign in and Register then you can add validationgroup for only one group SignIn and add validation group for SignIn only for three fields, Email, Password and Signin Button, then when click on Signin, then only two fields are going to validate., and register will work fine, you dont have to add any validationgroup for register

Comment: Hmm, well I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.
Both buttons now cause validation for all the fields, I wrote the new code in the original code, have a look, thanks!.
Note: in the code there are 2 validationGroups but with only 1 (for LogIn) it still does not work.

Comment: This is very basic c# code logic. You are making mistake in your code. Can you tell me what you are using to validation? There is no logic for validation in your code right now. you have to add required field validator to validate the field

Comment: Your password field is html input field, convert it to asp textbox

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't work, ValidationGroup refers to asp validation but I want separate html5 validation.